# R - incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Tags: r

Currently, I am writing my bachelor thesis in economics. One part of my work is a comparison of ETF returns and the returns of their benchmark indices. For this, I want to use an r-script. At the moment I have loading my raw closing prices in the program and named the tables "ETFs" and "Benchmark". My next step is to calculate the daily returns of the ETFs with this closing prices. I've started with a for-loop but it failed. 
The error term was:

```
Error in daylyreturn_ETFs[r, c] <- (ETFs[r, currColName]/ETFs[(r + 1),  : 
incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Varaibles:

ETFs:

```
 'data.frame':  1672 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ Name                                          : Factor w/ 1636 levels "01.02.2010","01.02.2011",..: 1608 1557 1502 1449 1252 1194 1139 1084 1029 863 ...
 $ iShares.Core.S.P.500.USD.Acc                  : num  203 203 206 205 205 ...
 $ iShares.Core.DAX.U.00AE...DE.                 : num  100 100 100 100 100 ...
 $ iShares.Core.MSCI.World.USD.Acc               : num  42 42.2 42.8 42.5 42.6 ...
 $ iShares.S.P.500.USD.Dist                      : num  21.2 21.3 21.7 21.6 21.5 ...
 $ iShares.EURO.STOXX.50..DE.                    : num  33.1 32.9 33 33 32.9 ...
 $ iShares.Core..U.0080..Corp.Bond.EUR.Dist      : num  130 130 130 130 130 ...
 $ Lyxor.Euro.Stoxx.50.DR.ETF.D.EUR.A.I          : num  31.9 31.9 32 32 32 ...
 $ iShares..U.0080..High.Yield.Corp.Bond.EUR.Dist: num  107 107 106 106 106 ...
 $ iShares.JP.Morgan...EM.Bond.USD.Dist          : num  104 104 105 104 104 ...
 $ iShares.MSCI.Europe.Dist                      : num  22.6 22.5 22.6 22.5 22.5 ...
 $ iShares.STOXX.Europe.600..DE.                 : num  36.1 36 36.1 36 36 ...
 $ iShares.EURO.STOXX.50.Dist                    : num  33.1 33.1 33.2 33.2 33.2 ...
 $ iShares.MSCI.World.USD.Dist                   : num  35.5 35.5 35.9 35.8 35.7 ...
 $ iShares.Edge.MSCI.USA.Size.Factor             : num  5.28 5.27 5.3 5.29 4.32 4.32 4.31 4.32 4.33 4.28 ...
 $ ETFS.Physical.Gold                            : num  106 106 106 105 104 ...
 $ iShares.iBonds.Mar.2020.Term.Corp.exFncl      : num  24.6 24.6 24.5 24.5 24.5 ...
 $ iShares.Euro.Corporate.Bond.Large.Cap         : num  135 135 135 135 135 ...
 $ db.x.trackers.Euro.Stoxx.50..DR..1D           : num  34.8 34.6 34.7 34.7 34.6 ...
 $ db.x.trackers.Euro.Stoxx.50..DR..1C           : num  44.1 44 44.1 44.1 44 ... 
 $ Xetra.Gold                                    : num  35.3 35.5 35.3 35 34.9 ...`
```

Code:

```
   library(readr)
werte <- read_delim("~/Uni Frankfurt/Semester 7/Bachelorarbeit/R/werte.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

library(readr)
werte1 <- read_delim("~/Uni Frankfurt/Semester 7/Bachelorarbeit/R/werte1.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

write.table(x=werte, file = "werte.dat", sep = ";", dec = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)

ETFs <- read.table("werte.dat", sep = ";", dec = ",", header = TRUE)

ETFs

write.table(x=werte1, file = "werte1.dat", sep = ";", dec = ".", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)

Benchmark <- read.table("werte1.dat", sep = ";", dec = ".", header = TRUE)

Benchmark

dailyreturn_ETFs<- array()

str(ETFs)

for(c in 2:ncol(ETFs))
{
  currColName <- colnames(ETFs)[c];
  for(r in nrow(ETFs[c])-1:1)
  {
    dailyreturn_ETFs[r,c] <- (ETFs[r,currColName]/ETFs[(r+1),currColName])-1
  }
}
```

I am very thankful for every help. If you need additional information the get rid of the problem don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Please try to recreate your problem with a minimal reproducible example, aka the smallest data set and the least code you can manage to recreate your question and issue. That will make it easier for us to help you, and more generalizable for other users who look to this question for advice.  Resource: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: need an example to troubleshoot, but its unlikely that you want `nrow(ETFs[c])-1:1` : compare the results of `nrow(mtcars)-1:1` to `(nrow(mtcars)-1):1` .